# How to Handle 100 Million Users - MySQL or NoSQL

Tags: mysql, configuration, nosql

I need a solution for social networking webapp, the DB structure is

1. users - login credentials.
2. user_order - user orders.
3. user_friends - user friends.

We expect a solution to handle 100 million users, whenever user logins I will have to query all the 3 tables.  XMPP will be used as messaging server for users to chat.

1. Should I use MySql or NoSQL?
2. Does MySql or NoSql impact the server performance?
3. What should be server's configuration?

Comment: Neither.  Postgres.

Answer (score 3):

I will advice you to hire a team of experienced database consultants. This is not a simple question which can be answered on serverfault.

First of all what type of NoSQL? Do you need integrity for your data? What will the database store, how much will it store, how intensive are the queries? If you have to ask such questions here you are already out of your league.